"ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package" error when running QGIS Plugin in PyCharm
I am trying to run a Plugin that I created in the Python debugger and it gives this error:

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package


Which appears to be related to this line:
# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
from . import resources

Not sure what I need to change?

I highly recommend structuring your plugin project directory like described in https://github.com/GispoCoding/qgis_plugin_tools?tab=readme-ov-file#plugin-tree-example . Then you can use absolute imports like from my_plugin.foo import bar and have not any import issues.

You need to be sure that the parent directory of your plugin directory is in your PYTHON_PATH in the python environment pycharm is using, and you need an __init__.py in your plugin directory.

Or open the parent directory of your plugin in PyCharm, not the plugin directory. This is so the working directory contains the plugin directory.  And, as mentioned earlier,  the plugin directory needs to contain an __init__.py so it will be treated as a package.
